# Magento 2 event before order is placed

Tags: magento, magento2

What event I should use after click on 'place order' in magento checkout and before order is placed

Where: 
Checkout -> Click "Place Order" -> (what event here) -> Order is placed

Answer (score 1):

There is a event called `sales_order_place_before` used for Place Order before.

Future Reference [Link](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-events.html), which have all Magento events.